# How to give a symbol a math slant to make it look like a math symbol when no slanted version exists in another font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{skull}
\begin{document}
I want $\skull$ to have a slight slant to it when 
used in math mode.  Other than editing the font, 
how can I achieve this?  There are no other fonts 
that I know of that have a slanted version of the 
$\skull$ symbol.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (So I'm looking for a poor man's slant.... ;-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be

```
\newcommand\fakeslant[1]{\pdfliteral{1 0 0.167 1 0 0 cm}#1\pdfliteral{1 0 -0.167 1 0 0 cm}}
\newcommand*\slskull{\fakeslant{\skull}}
```

There are a few answers in this site that use that fake slant.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not allowed to accept your answer yet.  And I hadn't come across such answers before I posted my question.

Comment: If it works well, could you add an image to the answer?

Comment: Have done.  My only complaint is that a hat on the symbol is not correctly placed, but I should be able to figure out elsewhere on the site how to address that issue.

Comment: @JPi I hope your next question is asking for a `\PirateHat` command

Comment: Aye aye matey @ChrisH.  I did figure out how to give the skull a hat.  My morbid question was inspired by the election results.